# List Comprehision with models in python

Tags: python, list, object, model, list-comprehension

I want to make a list of models with list comprehisions. This is my code:

```
class customers(object):
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        firstnames = ["aria", "ali", "behzad", "ahmad", "mohammad", "naser", "reza", "amirmohammad"]
        lastnames = ["banazadeh", "raiis", "rohani", "mahmod", "ahmady", "nejad", "alipor","behzadi"]

simplelist = [customers(firstname,lastname) for firstname in  firstnames for lastname in  lastnames]
for i in simplelist:
    print(i.firstname)
    print(i.lastname)
```

When I try to run this, the result is not what i want. The result is:

```
aria
banazadeh
aria
raiis
aria
rohani
ali
banazadeh
ali
raiis
ali
rohani
behzad
banazadeh
behzad
raiis
behzad
rohani
```

I want to only make customers with firstname and lastname quick and the result must be this:

```
aria
banazadeh
ali
raiis
behzad
rohani
```

Please help.

Comment: `simplelist = [customers(firstname, lastname) for firstname, lastname in zip(firstnames, lastnames)]`